# Android: bulk licensing?

Tags: android

A company would like to purchase a large number of licenses of my application.  They do not want to have individual device users make the purchase on their individual Google accounts.  Also, I would prefer not to build them an unlocked apk out of fear of it being distributed.  Do I have any intelligent option other then implementing some sort of license server, providing them with license keys, and associating license keys to device ids?

I searched a lot for solutions, but could not find anything.  Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A solution - create a second app that mirrors the original one but requires a password on start-up to activate.  Put that app on the market and give the company the password.

The good thing about this is that you do not require a license server. The bad, of course, is that if that password gets out into the wild, you're sunk.

Also , you could tell them the password and explain it's valid for one month. Either have the password automatically expire, or just push an update.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: build a special version of the app that has a challenge at first start-up, or even every so often. The challenge can be be a pseudo random number - even as simple as being part of the device's id. The response is some calculation of the challenge - e.g. munge it with today's date, and swap some bytes around.

You implement a web server that is password protected, you give that password to the company. Each time your web server is used to issue a new response code you increment the number of licenses consumed by the company.

The application presents the challenge, the user uses the company's password to log onto your web page, enter the challenge and receive the response. The application only registers if it is given the right response to the challenge. To give the customer more security you could have the response emailed to the user (have to give your their email address which the company may want to have for internal accounting purposes) and you could even block email addresses that are not in your customer's domain.

Its the company's responsibility to keep their password secure. They may want the ability to change the password in case it gets out in the wild such that unauthorized users are registering on their account.

The advantage is that this is a very simple system to set up, no license servers to set up nor associated hassles of distributing license keys, you have central control of (access to) the license numbers, and the responsibility lies on the company to keep its password secure.